# Angular - How can i pass a parameter into a deferred promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on my first Angular app here so excuse me if question not clear.

I have a service which `gets` from my api using a group variable in the header.

```
var theReq = {
   method: 'GET',
   url: API + '/homeq',
   headers: {
     'group': 'mobile'
   }
};

$http(theReq)
.then(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data);
})

self.getResults = function() {
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is with using the `group` variable that i specify rather than that preset one.

I can surely pass it into that function (i.e. `self.getResults = function(groupToGet)`)  but how would it get from there to `theReq` that I process?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your function in following manner. `$q` is the service to create deferred objects. You need to inject it.

```
self.getResults = function(groupToSet) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var theReq = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: API + '/homeq',
    headers: {
       'group': groupToSet
    }
  };

  $http(theReq)
  .then(function(data){
     deferred.resolve(data);
  })


  return deferred.promise;
}
```

and you can use promise as

```
self.getResults("mobile").then(function(data) {
  //success function here.
}).catch(function(error) {
  //error function here
});
```